# Keycloak behind Kong and strange redirect

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, keycloak, kong, kubernetes-helm

Setup:

- minikube version: v0.27.0
- Kong (helm install stable/kong) / version 1.0.2
- Keycloak (helm install stable/keycloak) / version 4.8.3.Final

I have a self signed SSL certificate for my "hello.local".

What I need to achieve: Keycloak behind Kong at "https://hello.local/".

My steps:

1) fresh minikube

2) Install Keycloak with helm, following values.yaml:

```
keycloak:
    basepath: ""
    replicas: 1
    ...
    extraEnv: |
      - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
        value: "true"
```

(that would create service `auth-keycloak-http`)

3) Install Kong with helm, following values.yaml:

```
replicaCount: 1
admin:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts: ['hello.local']
proxy:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts: ['hello.local']
    tls:
      - hosts:
        - hello.local
        secretName: tls-certificate
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  tls:
    enabled: true
postgresql:
...
```

4) I setup service and route for Kong

Service:

```
Protocol: http
Host: auth-keycloak-http
Port: 80
```

Route:

```
Hosts: hello.local
```

After that I can open "https://hello.local" and can see welcome page from Keycloak where I can click Administration Console and after that I have redirect to "https://hello.local:8443/admin/master/console/" in my browser. So we should not have redirect with another port at this point.

Setup with 2 docker images (Keycloak + Kong) is working if `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` is `true`.

How can I make Keycloak (helm chart) to work behind Kong (helm chart) in kubernetes cluster as expected, without redirect?

This is being discussed in [github issue 1](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/12272), [github issue 2](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/291) and [github issue 3](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/17). Also, Similar questions [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021042/cant-access-administration-console-page-with-keycloak-behind-kong-ingress-contr)

Comment: What is the question you're asking?

Comment: Question has been added, as well as extra links related to this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original answer:

Seems, it is necessary  to setup following environment variables in values.yaml of keycloak helm chart:

```
...
  extraEnv: |
    - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
      value: "80"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
      value: "443"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
      value: example.com
...
```

All of them are required, after that, redirect would work correctly.

**Added 2021 Sep:**

Issue with [weird behavior with redirect to port 8443](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/473) for some action (like go to Account management with the link on the top right of admin console).

In fact we do not need to set any `KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT`  or `KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT`.

Some changes are required on proxy side. On proxy we need to set `x-forwarded-port` to `443` for this route.

In my case we use Kong:

On the route, where Keycloak is exposed, we need to add (this one worked for me):

`serverless` > `post function` with following content:

```lua
ngx.var.upstream_x_forwarded_port=443
```

[More info on KONG and x_forwarded_*](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/5559#issuecomment-585972520)

Comment: There should be "hello.local" instead of "example.com"; am I right?

Comment: yes, however depends on the domain you are going to access keycloak

Comment: I am thinking about submitting a PR to the keycloak helm about adding these, even if they are commented out, spent too long trying to figure this out today :) Thank you!