# Can't access Administration Console page with keycloak behind Kong Ingress Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, kong

I have Keycloak behind Kong Ingress Controller.
I 'm able to see keycloak welcome page at my {url}/auth/. However, when I click at Administration Console I am redirected to {url}:8443/auth/admin/master/console/

When I click at Administration Console I should be redirect to {url}/auth/admin/master/console/

When I install keycloak (with helm) on minikube exposing the the service as a NodePort service without using ingress and load balancer I'm able to access Administration Console page.

I have detailed information about this problem in this link -> https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/17

I'm stuck in this and have no idea how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue may be a year ago, I remember that stupid redirect but I was not using Kong Ingress Controller, just a plain Kong. The problem I faced is that Kong runs as unprivileged user and cannot bind to low number ports. So Kong binds to 8443 ssl and places stupid redirect from 443 to 8443. I could not normally fix that and reinvented the wheel.

I used ports 80 and 443 for Kong:

```
    ports:
    - name: kong-proxy
      containerPort: 80
    - name: kong-proxy-ssl
      containerPort: 443
    - name: kong-admin
      containerPort: 8001
    - name: kong-admin-ssl
      containerPort: 8444
```

Then defined new ports and capability:

```
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    add:
    - NET_BIND_SERVICE
env:
  - name: KONG_PROXY_LISTEN
    value: 0.0.0.0:80, 0.0.0.0:443 ssl
  - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
    value: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
```

After that that stupid redirect disappeared.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, forgot to mention that for ports 80 and 443 to work I build custom Docker image with that lines:

```
FROM  kong:1.1.1-centos
RUN chown -R kong:kong /usr/local/kong \
    && setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/kong \
    && setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!
In my case I'm deploying both keycloak and kong in kubernetes using helm and there isn't this kind of options to configure the services.

Comment: What's the problem with editing Kong chart or even editing Kong deployment directly? Seems like easy job.

Comment: Yes @Vasily, editing kong chart is an easy job. When I read your comment for the first time I was so tired (trying to solve the problem) that I confused kong chart with keycloak chart. I was looking for the ports configuration in keycloak chart instead of kong chart rs.
So, as described in [kong chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kong), I changed the proxy.http.containerPort value from 8000 to 80, and changed proxy.tls.containerPort from 8443 to 443 but the pods crash (CrashLoopBackOff). With default values to the containerPort (8000 and 8443) kong works properly.

Comment: have you added environment variables and securityContext also? Can you see Kong logs to understand why it is crashing?

Comment: That's is the kong log message: [link](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/291#issuecomment-492877162)

Comment: Thanks for helping Vasily Angapov! Problem solved! The complete solution [here](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/291)